# framework7 with swiper.js swipe scroll to top not working

Tags: swiper.js, html-framework-7, phonegap-desktop-app

I have this function with swiper. I would like know how to use this function to scroll back to the top of the page of the next slide. so far it only scrolls to the top of the next slide when I use onAutoplay callback which I do not want. My slides has different text and images which scrolls that is why I want to return to the top of the next or previous slide when I swipe left or right. Please provide me with an example if possible how to improve my snippet. Thank you.

```
$$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
    var mySwiper = myApp.swiper('.swiper-container',{
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
      paginationHide: false,
      onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper) {
        $(".page-content").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
      }
    });                

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
mySwiper.on('slideChangeEnd',function(){ alert('sample alert');});
```

More information about the swiper API:
[Swiper API documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#parameters)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying this function

Comment: $$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
        var mySwiper = myApp.swiper('.swiper-container',{
          pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
          paginationHide: false,
          onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper) {
            $(".position").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 'slow');
          }
        });                

      })

Comment: but it is still not scrolling to the top of the next slide

Comment: I suppose the alert was not working before the modification I told you about. Now since you insist on initializing the swiper with only one function, change the onSlideChangeEnd to this: `onSlideChangeEnd: function('.swiper-container'){ the rest of your code here },`. I believe the problem is that since your swiper is not yet initialized, the program does not understand what "swiper" parameter you try to pass into the function.

Comment: `self.swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
          $(".page-content").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
          });
        });` try this its working on my code